# VS 2022: An error occured while loading the project properties editor. System.ArgumentException: Expected _ values Build::DefineConstants, but got _

Tags: version, visual-studio-2022, projects-and-solutions, configurationmanager, project-configuration

I use Visual Studio 17.3.5

I have this error: An error occured while loading the project properties editor. System.ArgumentException: Expected _ values Build::DefineConstants, but got _

Projects can't be loaded properly. There is a warning beside all faulty projects.

It happen when I was trying to working with projects configurations (Build-Configuration Manager). I was trying to add "x64" configuration. But I wasn't able to do so for 3 projects on 20. It was blocked (can't do it) but it seems that it worked in reality creating a new duplicate configuration for each of my try.

Answer (score 0):

I had an update to do, so I updated VS2022 to 17.3.6.
The update fixed my problem. But it is possible that a simple restart would have suffice. I don't remember I try it but I think so.